# Error FS3039: A direct reference to the generated type 'MyType' is not permitted

Tags: .net, f#, type-providers

The following type provider was intended to create `GeneratedNamespace.MyType` which accepts a static parameter of type `string` and contains only an empty constructor

```
namespace TypeProviderTest

open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices
open ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes
open System.Reflection
open System

[<TypeProvider>]
type MyTypeProvider(config:TypeProviderConfig) as this = 
    inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces()
    let namespaceName="GeneratedNamespace"
    let assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(config.RuntimeAssembly)

    //Provides definition, based on type parameters
    let instantiationFunction typeName (typeParams:obj[]) =
        match typeParams with
                | [|:? string as param|] -> 
                    //Creates an empty non-erased type
                    let definition = ProvidedTypeDefinition(
                                        assembly,
                                        namespaceName,
                                        typeName,
                                        Some typedefof<Object>,
                                        IsErased = false
                                        )

                    //Creates an empty constructor
                    let emptyCtor = ProvidedConstructor (parameters = [])
                    //Provides a call to base constructor 
                    //(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520352/)
                    //Doesn't seem to help
                    let objCtor = typedefof<Object>.GetType().GetConstructor([||])
                    emptyCtor.BaseConstructorCall <- (fun _ -> objCtor,[])
                    emptyCtor.AddXmlDoc("Empty constructor test")

                    definition.AddMember(emptyCtor)
                    definition
                | _ -> failwith "That was not supported"

    let  staticParams = [ProvidedStaticParameter("value",typedefof<string>)] 
    let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition(assembly,namespaceName,"MyType",Some typedefof<Object>)
    do t.DefineStaticParameters(staticParams,instantiationFunction)


    do this.AddNamespace(namespaceName,[t])
[<assembly:TypeProviderAssembly>]
do ()
```

When I try to use it like this

```
open System
open GeneratedNamespace
type X = MyType<"Abacaba">
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A %A" typedefof<X> (new X())
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

The line `type X = MyType<"Abacaba">` produces the error

> Error FS3039: A direct reference to the generated type 'MyType' is not
>   permitted.

I added a [base constructor call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520352/how-to-reference-generated-types-created-by-a-typeprovider), but it didn't help

The type provider is made generative intentionally

Is there an error in my type provider?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how to make it fully work, but I think the reason why you're getting the error is that the parameterised type is an erased type (while the type that you return once static parameters are provided is not an erased type).

Adding `IsErased = false` to `t` makes the error go away:

```
let  staticParams = [ProvidedStaticParameter("value",typedefof<string>)] 
let t = 
  ProvidedTypeDefinition
    (assembly,namespaceName,"MyType",Some typedefof<Object>,IsErased = false)
do t.DefineStaticParameters(staticParams,instantiationFunction)
```

With this, the code can be compiled, but trying to create an instance using `new X()` gives:

> error FS0192: internal error: null: GetTRefType

So, there is probably something else that I'm missing too. Perhaps it can point you into the right direction though!

Comment: Is it confirmed in docs, that parameterised type should be erased?

Comment: Found this https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack/issues/68

Comment: No, this is not related issue - it talks about _parameterized methods_. You can build generative type providers, you just need `IsErased=false` on both the parameterized type and the provided type.

Comment: "Generative" means that it's not erased, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, generative means that it's not erased.

Comment: But you say " You can build generative type providers, you just need `IsErased=false`". I can set it, add `InvokeCode = fun args -> <@@ obj() @@>` to `emptyCtor`, but then `typedefof<X>` will be `Object`, not `X`. I cannot build generative type providers by marking then as non-generative